# How do I use the opengl interface in Android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

If I want to use the opengl interface in android ndk, then will it be possible to show 
me a simple tutorial to let me master the android ndk？

I just wanna know how to operate in android ndk first.

Answer (score 1):

The sample in NDK san-angeles is not too simple for beginners. You can use it's Java part, because it is the bare minimum for setting up a native OpenGL application. Then you can fill the JNI functions nativeInit, nativeResize and nativeRender with the OpenGL code.